# Fetch all defined colors using DBpedia and SPARQL

Tags: rdf, wikipedia, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

How can I query DBpedia to get the names and hex codes of all color values (i.e., any use of the `color` infobox) in Wikipedia? The [Spring Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_green) article uses the `color` template as follows:

```
{{infobox color|
 title=Spring Green|textcolor=black|
 hex=00FF7F|
 r= 0|g= 255|b= 127|sRGB=1
 c=100|m=0|y=50|k=0|
 h=150|s=100|v=100<ref>{{cite web|url=http://web.forret.com/tools/color.asp?RGB=%2300FF7F|title=web.forret.com Color Conversion Tool set to hex code of color #00FF7F (Spring Green):}}</ref>
 |source=[[Web colors#X11 color names|X11]]}}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following query:

```
select distinct ?colour ?hex where {
  ?colour a dbpedia-owl:Colour .
  ?colour dbpprop:hex ?hex .
}
```

see the results [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?colour%20?hex%20where%20%7B?colour%20a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour%3E%20.%20?colour%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/hex%3E%20?hex%7D&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).

also the following query:

```
select distinct ?colour ?hex where {
  ?colour a dbpedia-owl:Colour .
  ?colour dbpedia-owl:colourHexCode ?hex .
}
```

and the [result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?colour%20?hex%20where%20%7B?colour%20a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour%3E%20.%20?colour%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/colourHexCode%3E%20?hex%7D%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).

Comment: The hex values seem to be nonsensical for many of the colors.

Comment: I think it's because dbpedia groups down "variants" of a color into the parent color e.g. Many shades of blue go into the "blue" node. So the hex is per a particular shade of blue but it doesn't know which. So you have to traverse down into the variant and back up again if the color has variants.

Comment: I think DBpedia doesn't do much with color variants, there's no inference of that kind.

Comment: The two queries look similar, but are actually very different - http://dbpedia.org/property/hex is a raw property. For example, the first query claims that the New Hampshire Wildcats have a property called "hex" with the value 337.0° Fahrenheit, because the infobox contains the line hex1=00337F, which the raw DBpedia extractor treats with certain heuristics and comes up with that wild property.

Comment: The mapping based extractor, on the other hand, knows that the New Hampshire Wildcats are not a color, and also knows that colors have a hex code that should be extracted as a string, not as an integer. Thus the values in the second query are much cleaner. It uses the 'clean' property http://dbpedia.org/ontology/colourHexCode . See http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Mapping:Infobox_color and http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyProperty:ColourHexCode .